# AngularJS - Page loads before scope variable is initialised

Tags: angularjs

I am initialising a scope variable to false in controller

```
$scope.created=false;
```

However when the page loads for the fist time still the below message flickers once and then hides. Is there a way to stop this flicker and hide it fully when the page loads for the first time.

```
<div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="created">A new Entity created successfully.</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add `ng-cloak` to your div, it hides it until the controller is loaded.

Comment: Thanks it works fine when loading the page for first time.. But when I click refresh it does not work properly and shows this banner. Any other way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Jay,

You can try this:

```
<div ng-init="created=false">
    <div class="alert alert-success" ng-show="created">A new Entity created successfully.</div>
</div>
```

And finally you can create a function that makes the variable created be true.

Look an example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IvHYePK8ydB1FzLhQajl?p=preview)